# Eclipse insists on opening java files in Sublime

Tags: eclipse, sublimetext2

We recently upgraded our copies of Sublime.  Problem is now our developers that use eclipse are having trouble opening java files.  It seems that Eclipse has for one reason or another decided that half of the java files should be opened with "Java Editor" (when you right click and go to Open With) and the other half should open in "System Default" which as it turns out, is Sublime.

Where is the button I press to reset this stupid thing so Eclipse will open java files in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse "remembers" when files were "Open with"-ed with a certain Viewer and opens that file always with that Viewer from than on (it gets highlighted in the Options list and overrides the file-association).

You could try to change it back to the default by choosing "Default Editor" in the "Open with" context menu option in Project Explorer for each file that behaves strange.

Answer (score 0):

The default editor for a file type can be set through `Window>Preferences>General>Editors>File Associations`. If multiple editors are set for `.java` and it's bugging out then possibly removing all editors except the default will help.

Comment: Been there, tried that.  Every time I try to change it there, it comes back saying that the file type is locked by content types.  i go to content types and it says its locked by file types.  Classic eclipse